# New style of first person pov

Tags: language, narrative, grammatical-person

I was thinking about my own style of writing. Turn out, in every role play I've written, I have a good writing style when I use the first person pov. I'll add some "voices" to the main character. (like a schizophrenic) I've already done it, and everybody was really enjoying all the jokes and situation created with them.

So, I would like to use this to write a SF roman. A full one.
So, some questions/debates:

1. The narration. I'm thinking of not using the narration at all. Everything will be the main character's mind. So, dialogues can be a little hard to write and follow if more than 2 people. (No ", she said." Just the dialogue, with no indication, and the thoughts before and after should be enough to understand.) And the description of city, places, will be just enough for the characters, but that's all. I'm really bad in narrative description, so, the action and the places will not be detailed. Just the necessary.
2. The voices. I want to use them with different police, italic, etc... Should be the main one, the main character's thoughts. 2 more, for fun and extra fun. And some other when drunk etc.
3. Language. When we talk in our head, we don't use a formal style. I'm French, and I think I will use contraction like "I'm", forgetting some words to make it more like a casual talk. And some (many) "bad words" too.
4. The plot. I didn't imagine a plot and story yet. It will take place in a world post-apocalyptic, similar to borderlands (the game). I'm afraid the special style of writing will create a story a bit empty for a SF Roman, and maybe to much axed on the jokes of the voices.

So ? What you guys do you think about this ? Have some advice or else before I start ?
(If you read something similar, please say so. I think it's pretty original, but I'm maybe wrong)

Comment: We're a Q&A site, and we can't really offer you feedback on a new style that we haven't read and that you haven't yet written! But a good general guideline is: if something sounds cool and fun to you, **try it**. See how it comes out. If nothing else, it'll have been a fun experiment - and do _treat it_ as an experiment, which in all probability you'll discard when you're done. (This is a healthy approach for _anybody's_ first attempt at writing a novel.) Try. Enjoy. Don't get too attached to it. See what happens.

Answer (score 8):

> The narration. I'm thinking of not using the narration at all.

Please don't do this.

It is very, *very* hard to understand even when handled by a master. If this is your first book, it will be almost impossible for your readers to follow.

My suggestion for you is this: Start a blog, and write short stories, flash fiction, or chapters of your book using this style. Show it to your friends and get feedback. Find out if your audience likes what you are writing and how it's written.

If it works, you can figure out your plot (or if you are a discovery writer, just get started). If it doesn't work, you can find out from your readers what is not working.

I salute your enthusiasm and your desire to write. Ce sont bons! But "writing for fun" still has to be guided by rules to be readable by others.

Comment: Yep.  Not a good idea.  Not for your first book.  Or the second.  Or the third.  You need to learn good habits not bad ones when you're at the beginning.

Comment: Great stories are great almost no matter how they're told so why depend upon a new method to tell a story? Mostly it will just exclude a large percentage of readers. This reminds me of stream-of-consciousness like Kerouac's Big Sur (https://www.amazon.com/Big-Sur-Jack-Kerouac-ebook/dp/B00601W8L2/ref=as_li_ss_tl?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1464803273&sr=8-1&linkCode=ll1&tag=radink-20&linkId=a14badca6f03cca06784f19ae185b171 ) Not my thing.